# PHP How to call two functions in one line?

Tags: php

I'm trying something new for me:

```
class bar {
    public function outside(){
        function inside(){
            return "baz";
        }
    } 
}

$foo = new bar();
```

I want call two functions **in one line** (some like this):

```
echo $foo->outside()->inside(); // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function inside() on null
```

I thought it would return "*baz* but not. How I can build this syntax?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Nested named functions are extremely discouraged.

Comment: `inside()` would have to be a function of `bar`, and `outside()` would have to return a reference to `$this` for chaining to work like that (or something along those lines).

Comment: This is called "fluent", which should give you a keyword for research which will yield lots of examples.